# Make a cell of a table display a larger picture of a smaller one, on mouse over

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Is there any function or command that I can use to take the "pop-up" picture from this function:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
    <img src="productURL" width="100px" height="142px" border="0" />
    <span>
        <img src="productURL" />
        <br />
        <font face="arial">productname</font> 
    </span>
</a>
```

Be displayed in a table located to the right of the page?

Notes:
I'm using Dreamweaver CS6

Maybe there's a way to put, inside a class, that the pop up has to be shown inside a table, defined earlier?

Comment: @kelly thanks for the sugestion. i'm kinda new to HTML

Comment: There is now <table> tags in your html code.  Having a hard time figuring out what the problem is here?

Comment: Yes I am. I got a CSS that is just like Xfactor's, who posted his answer here. But I can't figure out a way of putting the popup into a fixed location, which is in a 1x1 table located 70% off the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**
you can do that by this

in your html table cell tag add an id

**HTML**

```
<img src = "xyz.png" onmouseover="showimage();" onmouseout="hideimage();" />
```

and for table

```
<table><tr><td id="showimage"></td></tr></table>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showimage()
{
    document.getElemtnById('showimage').append('<img src="xyz">');
}

function hideimage()
{
    var elem = document.getElemtnById('showimage');
    elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already got it coded. I wanted to make the "pop-up" be displayed on a cell of a table, located 70% from the left of the page

Comment: use jquery, rather than showing it in div just paste the code in your table. regards

Comment: the host of my site won't give support for jquery, so i need to do it with HTML or Javascript

Comment: use javascript, call hover function and display image in that table (give id to that cell on which you want to show the image, then just assign that cell an image to show). Regards

Comment: ok, i'll look up some tutorial on JavaScript on the web and then report back. I got started in webdesign this week, so i pretty much know nothing, except for a brief background on programming logic

Comment: I have edited and inserted the javascript code for you, just check it if it helps you any way. Regards

Comment: The script didn't work, but I figured out. On the last class i've put .thumbnail:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 25%;
    left: 75%;
} and it worked out just as i wanted. Thank you for your help, you made me think of this

Comment: haha :) Ok i am glad that you got it on your own. Well thanks to you too.